# How can I improve Scala's type inference with type parameters that don't show up in the first parameter list?

Tags: generics, scala, parameters, type-inference

To illustrate my point, here an example:

```
abstract class Wrapper[A](wrapped: A) {

  protected def someCondition: Boolean

  def fold[B](whenTrue: => B)(whenFalse: => B): B =
    if (someCondition) whenTrue else whenFalse

}
```

I'm trying to add a `fold` method based on an arbitrary condition defined on a wrapped type `A`. The problem with the code above is that this wouldn't compile, although it could conceivably return `Any`:

```
wrapper.fold("hi")(42)
```

because by the time the compiler reaches the second parameter list, `B` has already been inferred to be `String`. Suppose we don't want to have to write the type annotation. We can try changing `fold` to this:

```
def fold[B, B0 >: B](whenTrue: => B)(whenFalse: => B0): B0
```

but this *also* doesn't work, since `B0` has already been resolved as `String` at the end of the first parameter list, although it doesn't appear in it at all! The simple solution, of course, is to have a single parameter list, but f the sake of the example, let's say I want to keep the two parameter lists and try to make it work… Ideally, we should be able to *delay* the resolution of `B0`. It would be great if we could write something like this:

```
def fold[B](whenTrue: => B)[B0 >: B](whenFalse: => B0): B0
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Are there any workarounds?

*(I'm providing a first answer, but I'm of course looking for other workarounds as well.)*

Comment: It really looks like an issue that can be handled slightly differently with the `Either`class, have you considered this possibility ?

Comment: @Nicolas I fail to see how using `Either` would help the compiler infer the most specific common super types of the params `whenTrue` and `whenFalse`, but feel free to propose an answer, I'd be very interested to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a temporary instance of a class that defines an `apply` method simulating the second parameter list, which has itself the `B0` type parameter:

```
abstract class Wrapper[A](wrapped: A) {

  // ... as before...

  def fold[B](whenTrue: => B) = new FoldRequest[B](whenTrue)

  class FoldRequest[B](whenTrue: => B) {
    def apply[B0 >: B](whenFalse: => B0) =
      if (someCondition) whenTrue else whenFalse
  }
}
```

Then everything works correctly. Could we even imagine that `def fold[B](whenTrue: => B)[B0 >: B](whenFalse: => B0): B0` could be interpreted as syntactic sugar for this?…

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you want to mimic, thanks to compilation, the behavior and the goal of the `Either` class.
What you can do is the following: your fold will return an `Either` object and get your B0 value from it:

```
abstract class Wrapper[A](wrapped: A) {

  protected def someCondition: Boolean

  def fold[A, B](whenTrue: => B)(whenFalse: => A): Either[A, B] =
    Either.cond(someCondition, whenTrue, whenFalse)

}
```

And let the implicit conversion `either2mergeable` of the `Either`class do the work:

```
scala> new Wrapper[Unit] {def someCondition = true}
res0: Wrapper[Unit] = $anon$1@77026e40

scala> res0.fold(42)("hi").merge
res1: Any = 42
```

Pro:

- The `Either` structure allow you to directly retrieve A and B types
- You can check what part was applied during fold

Con:

- You do not obtain the result directly

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I can just call `merge` on the resulting either without the `RichEither` trick. But this only helps partially, as I still need that extra annoying `merge` call, which is actually just boilerplate…

Comment: Yep, I've just re-created MergeableEither and the merge function, thanks for pointing it, I will adapt my answer. If you want to avoid merge, maybe an `implicit def toAnswer[A](e: Either[A, A]) => A`is the answer ?

Comment: forget the implicit idea: As Soon as the common type is `Any`, it will not work.